# ¿Como importo una llave primaria compuesta en SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo dos entidades:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPRA(
IDCOMPRA INT NOT NULL,
IDCLIENTES INT,
PEDIDO INT,
IDPRENDA INT,
TOTAL NUMBER(8,2),
CONSTRAINT PKCOMPRA
PRIMARY KEY (IDCOMPRA)
);
```

Y pedido:

```
CREATE TABLE PEDIDO(
IDCOMPRA INT,
IDPRENDA INT,
TOTAL NUMBER (8,2),
CONSTRAINT PKPEDIDO
PRIMARY KEY (IDCOMPRA,IDPRENDA)
);
```

la cosa es poder acceder a todas las compras que hizo un cliente con un solo numero de compra.
¿De qué me sirve la entidad pedido si de todas maneras para hacer a pedido llave foranea necesito la entidad Prenda para importarla?
Estoy bastante confundido.

Comment: Parece que están mal esas tablas. Podrías explicar la consigna?

Comment: Hola, claro. Es una tienda de ropa donde existen las entidades Cliente, Compra y Prenda, cada uno con sus respectivos ID. La cuestión es que como las llaves primarias no se pueden repetir (En este caso la de compra) entonces solo me permitiría realizar una compra de articulo por cada IDCompra... ¿No? Y no sé como asignar muchas prendas a un solo ID de compra

Comment: No termino de entender el problema. Un ID, es unico, eso lo tienes que tener claro. Partiendo de eso, no entiendo si lo que quieres es hacer una consulta en php para hacer compras y mostrarlas, o hacer nuevas modificaciones en la BBDD. Hay unas reglas muy simples, en ER(entidad relacion) para crear la relacion entre las tablas y asi sale que campo es FK y PK. Si amplias un poco el problema, te podremos ayudar mejor.

Comment: La clave primaria es única **en su propia tabla**, y no necesariamente es única en las tablas donde funciona como clave foránea. Ahora bien, en cada tabla deberías tener una clave primaria, independiente de las claves foráneas. Por lo que veo en tu tabla pedido, su clave primaria la compones de IDCOMPRA (que supongo es la clave foránea que hace referencia a tu talba compra) e IDPRENDA, que supongo es clave foránea a PRENDA. Esto ya es dependiendo de cada programador, pero en la tabla PEDIDO yo haría una clave primaria IDPEDIDO autoincrementable.